# Graphing two dataframe columns on different axis with different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to plot two columns of a dataframe, one that would have a Log Yscale and the other would have a regular one. I am not sure what the syntax would be, the documentation doesn't help too much either. Can anyone advise what the proper syntax would be, and how to learn how matplotlib works in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pandas provides an option to plot on a [secondary y axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis). Besides that, you only need to change the scale of the secondary axis with `.set_scale('log')`.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,0,4], 'y': [1e1, 5e3, 3e2, 3e4]})

ax = df.plot(secondary_y='y')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot with secondary y in log scale]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_base = np.arange(2,11)
arr_log = np.log(arr_base)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((arr_base, arr_log)).T, columns=['a', 'b'])

fig = plt.figure()
sub_plot = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
sub_plot.plot(arr_base)
sub_plot.plot(arr_log)
plt.savefig('myplot.svg')
```

A great resource for learning the basics of matplotlib, especially in connection with pandas, is Wes McKinney's book, "[Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do)." Not only does it have a nice introduction to matplotlib in Chapter 8 (you can find something very close to my example on page 228 and others), but it is an essential reference if your planning on using pandas much and also gives a good introduction to numpy.

The [homepage](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) for matplotlib also has links to some tutorials. They also maintain a [page of example uses](http://matplotlib.org/examples/). Both are solid resources.